# Why is there no `Default` implementation for `T::AccountId`?

Tags: frame, runtime, account

Starting with version 9.17 and greater I started getting these errors for the custom pallets I've made. Could I please get a pointer in resolving this issue? Example output from compiler:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Default, Encode, Decode, scale_info::TypeInfo)]
   |                                       ^^^^^^^
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `frame_support::traits::Get<SolanaAccount<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>` for `GetDefault`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `QueryKindTrait<SolanaAccount<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>, GetDefault>` for `frame_support::pallet_prelude::ValueQuery`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `frame_support::storage::generator::StorageMap<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, SolanaAccount<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>` for `frame_support::pallet_prelude::StorageMap<_GeneratedPrefixForStorageSolMnemonic<T>, frame_support::Twox64Concat, <T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, SolanaAccount<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>, frame_support::pallet_prelude::ValueQuery>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `frame_support::StorageMap<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, SolanaAccount<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>` for `frame_support::pallet_prelude::StorageMap<_GeneratedPrefixForStorageSolMnemonic<T>, frame_support::Twox64Concat, <T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, SolanaAccount<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>, frame_support::pallet_prelude::ValueQuery>`
   = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Default` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
help: consider further restricting the associated type
   |
97 |     #[pallet::storage, <T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId: std::default::Default]
```

Comment: It's a little bit too little context to provide a useful answer. Consider augmenting the question with a little bit more detail.

Comment: You may find this PR useful https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/10403

Comment: I have a struct of many different chain addresses to attach to a user. I used T::AccountId for the dot address reference, I suppose I can change it to Vec<u8>. Its convenient to use the macro on those structs as it saves many lines of code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short answer: `AccountId` is not designed to be bound to `Default`. A "default" `AccountId` doesn't make any sense to have and it helped mask a previous issue and so it was removed in a recent release.

This means that `AccountId` values cannot be used as storage item values which assume a default value.

In your case, you'll probably need to replace the `ValueQuery` with an `OptionQuery` and handle the possibility that the map item doesn't exist (i.e. that it returns `None`). An alternative would be to manually implement `Default` for `SolanaAccount<AccountId>` when `AccountId` doesn't itself implement `Default`.

Comment: I just manually impl Default for it. Thanks!

Comment: @AaronEly please consider marking this answer as the solution, thanks.

Comment: @AaronEly 

can you provide the code snippet to implement Default for AccountId.