# How to do a manual implementation for 'AccountId'

Tags: pallet, frame, account

I am working on creating a custom map which takes `T::AccountId` as a perimeter:

```rs
#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::getter(fn declaration_map)]
pub(super) type Declarations<T: Config> = StorageMap
<
_,
Blake2_128Concat,
T::AccountId,
Amendment<T::AccountId>,
OptionQuery
>;
```

I pass it as an `OptionQuery` since `AccountId` does not have a default value implemented and therefore could be `None` value. However in my calls: (Example)

```rs
#[pallet::weight(100_000)]
pub fn add_amendment(origin: OriginFor<T>, statement: Vec<u8>, owners: Vec<T::AccountId>) -> DispatchResult {
    use crate::pallet::Event::AmendmentAdded;
    ensure_root(origin)?;
    let amendment = Amendment {
                  statement: statement.clone(), 
                  owners: owners
                };
    let next_id = Self::next_amendment();
    Declarations::<T>::insert(next_id, amendment);
    Self::deposit_event(AmendmentAdded(next_id.unwrap(), statement));
    NextAmendmentID::<T>::put(&next_id.unwrap() + 1);
    Ok(())
}
```

When I get a value from the map there is a potential that the value will be `None` and can not be used as a key. The simplest way to fix this in my mind is to implement a default value to `AccountId`. My question is how do I implement that? There is an this article:
[Why is there no `Default` implementation for `T::AccountId`?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1812/why-is-there-no-default-implementation-for-taccountid)
The OP however doesn't go into detail about how they implemented a default value. If anyone has any insight on this it would be very helpful.

Comment: Sounds like you should return an error if the value is none instead of trying to implement default. In the case there is no account id, probably your logic is invalid, and should not be executed. Otherwise, please improve your code samples to be something which is complete, and can be edited to be correct. As is, you are leaving so many questions about other types and storage.