# core::default::Default` is not implemented for `<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId`

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-node-template

> use frame_support::pallet_prelude::*;
> use frame_system::pallet_prelude::*;
> use scale_info::{prelude::vec};
> use frame_support::inherent::Vec;

```
#[pallet::pallet]
#[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store)]
#[pallet::without_storage_info]
pub struct Pallet<T>(_);




/// Configure the pallet by specifying the parameters and types on which it depends.
#[pallet::config]
pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
    /// Because this pallet emits events, it depends on the runtime's definition of an event.
    type RuntimeEvent: From<Event<Self>> + IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::RuntimeEvent>;
}

#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::getter(fn user)]
pub type User<T:Config> = StorageValue<_, T::AccountId, ValueQuery>;
```

If I want to add this line then i get the error:  pub type User<T:Config> = StorageValue<_, ***T::AccountId***, ValueQuery>;
[image]

But I'm successfully able to add this: pub type User<T:Config> = StorageValue<_, ***Vec<T::AccountId>***, ValueQuery>;

How to solve the above error ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is there no \`Default\` implementation for \`T::AccountId\`?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1812/why-is-there-no-default-implementation-for-taccountid)  
You can use `OptionQuery` instead of `ValueQuery`.